# Generate CSV file from dataset C#

Tags: c#, csv, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I'm using following code to generate CSV file.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                      Select(column => column.ColumnName);
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
}
File.WriteAllText("test.csv", sb.ToString());
```

How can I give the path to save CSV file in here?

Comment: "How can I give the path to save CSV file in here?" -- Do you already have the path? Then you can just use `Path.Combine`: `File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(thePath, "test.csv"), sb.ToString());`, will write to: `{thePath}\test.csv`, e.g., for `thePath = @"C:\myPath"`, will write to `C:\myPath\test.csv`.

Comment: This question needs a lot of clean up. The title has nothing to do with the question being asked. The code 90% of the code provided also has nothing to do with the question being asked. There is no indication of what has already been tried. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: File.WriteAllText("test.csv", sb.ToString()); will save the csv in the exe path, What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right you want to enter a path (folder) with the file name, use e.g.:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\FolderXXX\test.csv", sb.ToString());
```